# Retain Value if it's the Only One in Group, Otherwise Filter Out

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
dat <- data.frame(account = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
                  group = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d"),
                  status = c("active", "inactive", "inactive", "inactive", "active", "open", "inactive", "active", "active"))
```

And I want to filter such that each group (`a`, `b`, or `c`) has at least one account. So only accounts where the status is `active` or `open` are kept, **unless** the only status in a group is `inactive`.

How would I go about filtering that?

I think I could do it in multiple calls, but is there a way to do it in one line?

```
active_open <- dat %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    filter(status == "active" | status == "open") %>%
    ungroup()

inactive <- dat %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    filter(n_distinct(status) == 1 & status == "inactive") %>%
    slice_head(n = 1) %>%
    ungroup()

dat_clean <- bind_rows(active_open, inactive)
```

This works, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `filter` like below

```
dat %>%
    filter(
        if (all(status == "inactive")) {
            !duplicated(status)
        } else {
            status != "inactive"
        }, .by = group)
```

which gives

```
  account group   status
1       1     a   active
2       3     b inactive
3       5     c   active
4       6     c     open
```

Comment: Sorry I should have provided a better data example. I've updated my data. This doesn't work when there is a group with only inactive and more than 1 inactive accounts.

Comment: @setty I didn't see the difference between your output and mine

Comment: I've updated the data I supplied before. With your code, I get two rows for group `b`, both of which are inactive. I'm trying to only retain one `inactive` record if `inactive` is the only status found in a group.

Comment: This works! And it works well if there are additional statuses I need to keep and only one I need to exclude. Can you elaborate on the if part though? I'm not quite understanding
`if (all(status == "inactive")) {  !duplicated(status) }`

Comment: @setty it marks the second and following “inactive” as False